# nginx and wordpress in subdirectory results in access denied

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have two rails apps and a wordpress running on the same domain. The rails apps run fine, but I cannot get the wordpress working out of a subdirectory. It works from served from root.

I get the following error in nginx error.log. Note the double wordpress in the path, that's the problem, but I don't know how to resolve it! The true path is /var/www/wordpress and not /var/www/wordpress/wordpress!

```
2017/12/16 21:15:18 [error] 17341#17341: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access 
to the script '/var/www/wordpress/wordpress' has been denied (see 
security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, 
client: ...
```

Here's my nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/first_rails_app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_root /var/www/first_rails_app/;
    passenger_document_root /var/www/first_rails_app/public;
    rails_env    production;

    index index.htm index.html;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location /wordpress {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        index index.php;
        passenger_enabled off;

        location ~ .php(?|$) {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            #passenger_enabled off;
        }                        
    }

    location ~ ^/second_rails_app(/.*|$) {
        alias /var/www/second_rails_app/public$1;  # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
        passenger_base_uri /second_rails_app;
        passenger_app_root /var/www/second_rails_app/;
        passenger_document_root /var/www/second_rails_app/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

}
```

Comment: You need to edit the `security.limit_extensions` option in php-fpm configuration. It's probably configured to allow only `.php` files

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    root /var/www/wordpress;
```

Your `try_files` line says look for the requested file, if its not found check if it's a directory, if that doesn't work either then serve root directory + `/wordpress/index.php?$args`, which is `/var/www/wordpress/wordpress/index.php?$args`

For Wordpress this should work

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`